# Python property setter decoration of a list object

Tags: python, list, decorator, setter

```
globalList = []
class MyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myList = [1, 2, 3]

    @property
    def myList(self):
        return self.myList.extend(globalList)
    @myList.setter
    def myList(self):
        return self.myList
mL1 = MyList()
print("myList: ", mL1.myList)
mL1.myList.append(4)
print("after appending a 4, myList: ", mL1.myList)
```

my goal is to be able to call mL1.myList which evaluates the myList instance attribute and a global object globalList, but here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Dropbox\sandbox.py", line 14, in <module>
    mL1 = MyList()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Dropbox\sandbox.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.myList = [1, 2, 3]
TypeError: myList() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you seem to be misusing properties.  The property setter (what you create with `myList.setter`) is what gets called when you do `mL1.myList = something`.  It needs to accept another argument, which is the value `something` which the property is to be set to.  If all you want is to be able to read `mL1.myList`, why do you need a setter at all?  What do you want the setter to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems.  Probably the biggest one is that you can't give your property the same name as the underlying attribute that it reads.  If in your `myList` getter, you do `self.myList`, it will cause an infinite recursion, because in order to find out what `self.myList` is it has to call the property getter again.

To avoid this you should have the getter and setter reference some other attribute, conventionally the same name but preceded by an underscore.  That is, for your case, use a "hidden" attribute `_myList` to store the value that the property gets/sets.

Second, your property setter needs to accept an argument for the value that you want to set the property to, and it needs to set the underlying attribute to that value.

Finally, you are returning the result of `extend`, but `extend` modifies the list in place and returns None, so your code will result in `None` as the value of `mL1.myList`.

Your code should look more like this:

```
globalList = []
class MyList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myList = [1, 2, 3]

    @property
    def myList(self):
        return self._myList + globalList
    @myList.setter
    def myList(self, val):
        self._myList = val
```

If you're using Python 3, as it seems you are, then you can just do `class MyList:` instead of `class MyList(object):`.

Comment: Clear a few misunderstanding I had! Thank you.